# listing submitted jobs in HDInsight

Tags: azure-hdinsight

Is there any option to get a list of all submitted jobs in HDInsight without using remote desktop?? (thro .net SDK or web interface)

1. There is a function 'ListJobs'.

But it shows exception '502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server'

2  Also I am not able to access the jobtracker portal with the namenode IP(IP of remote desktop).

(http://:50030/jobtracker.jsp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WebHCat for this.
Send a GET request to https:///templeton/v1/jobs with showall set to True.

Documentation of the API is [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+Jobs)

This will return all job ids submitted and visible to the user Id you authenticate in with.

Providing the curl command just for completeness of solution.

```
curl -i -u <clusterUserName>:<clusterPassword> -d user.name=<JobSubmissionUserName> -d showall=true -s "https://<clusterDnsName>..azurehdinsight.net/templeton/v1/jobs"
```

Answer (score 1):

On newly created HDInsight windows cluster "YARN status page" is accessible remotely which lists YARN jobs. Check blog here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiny_bits/archive/2015/09/19/yarn-status-page-with-out-rdp-into-cluster.aspx

Note that these are YARN jobs not Templeton jobs.

Answer (score 0):

On newly created HdInsihgt windows clusters "YARN status page" is exposed in "Query console" in browser. This will show any YARN job not just Templeton jobs.